# sql query to get records 12 unique months records of every year, every year has set different volume number

Tags: sql

i want to get 12 records of distinct months of every year, if volume column has 1 value for year 2013 so query should return 2013 years distinct months if exist, this should have same for different volume123 means year2013,2014,2015

```
select distinct month(date_publication) as pmonth,p.volume,p.* from tbl_Papers p
where adminStatus='PUBLISHED'
```

eg.:if year is 2013 so in volume column value is ('1')

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Show us the table structure, some sample data and expected output. Also tag the question with DBMS that you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Do a PIVOT..  For example..

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT top 1
YEAR(date_publication) as [YEAR]
,LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, date_publication), 3) AS MONTH
,volume
,COUNT(1) AS Amount
FROM  tbl_Papers (nolock)
WHERE adminStatus='PUBLISHED'
) as s
PIVOT
(
    sum(Amount)
    FOR [month] IN (JAN, FEB, MAR, APR, 
    MAY, JUN, JUL, AUG, SEP, OCT, NOV, DEC)
)
as PVT
```

And this will show by 2012, 2013, etc.